# Detect adblock with php

Tags: php, ads, adblock

I'd like to ask whether there is any PHP solution for detecting adblock - I only found javascript solutions which are not any help for me.

The problem is, I want to keep the site accessible, but a certain PHP script running on the site should be blocked when the adblock is detected. So the user may view the website, and when the user uses a form, the form does some PHP stuff, but when he uses adblock, the PHP file should just return an error message.

Any help? Thanks!
(really couldn't find anything that would help me..)

Comment: AdBlock blocks the *browser* from requesting specific resources. You need to use javascript to test it. Surely you could tell your PHP something with javascript? (*Psst - ajax!*)

Comment: @h2ooooooo Which of course could _also_ get blocked by AdBlock depending on how smart it becomes ;)

Comment: @sjagr Very true, but then your site would have to be part of AdBlocks filters which, unless you're a huge site, is unlikely.

Comment: @h2ooooooo I was thinking more of the lines of a library detection. Say `adblock_detect.min.js` becomes a popular library (or already is), for example.

Comment: I don't really have any knowledge of ajax, could you possibly give me a hint on how to make this?

Comment: You can use AJAX indeed. Lets say when a page loads, you require your ajax script (with a separate src from other ajax) to send you a key. If the key received from ajax didn't match the one on the session or your php didn't receive the key for x+2 sessions, then you know you are running charity sessions.

Comment: ask visitor politely to turn off the ad blocker by use this way
https://blockadblock.com/ or https://www.detectadblock.com/

Answer (score 1):

PHP is server side code and cannot read whats on the clients computer. You should use Javascript or AJAX to send information to the php server and then act on it.

Answer (score 0):

No, that is not possible. Because php is *server-side* and as such is totally agnostic of what a user is doing / has installed in it's browser. *But* you can ofcourse let Javascript send out a call (using AJAX) to the server, telling if an adblocker has been installed, and depending on that call, run a script, or do nothing. Easy does it!

Comment: Well, is there any open-source solution for that - I mean do you know of any? Because I'm totally lost in AJAX..

Comment: @Imro If you wish to use jQuery, `jQuery.ajax` is very easy. There's thousands (probably *billions*) of tutorials about it